# Override breadcrumbs is not present?

Tags: views, 8, breadcrumbs

In Drupal 7, in the views with an argument, is easy to override both title and breadcrumbs.

[image: Drupal 7 Views configuration]

Now in Drupal 8 I can't find the option.

[image]

Did I miss something? or isn't possible? In this case what is the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few workarounds:

1) You may need to look in to creating a service in a custom module example:
yourmodule.service.yml

```
services:
  someviews.breadcrumb:
    class: Drupal\yourmodule\HelpBreadcrumbBuilder
    arguments: ['@entity.manager']
    tags:
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 701 }
```

Then in yourmodule/src/HelpBreadcrumbBuilder.php

```
namespace Drupal\yourmodule;

use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb;
use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\BreadcrumbBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;

/**
 * Provides a breadcrumb builder for whatever.
 */
class HelpBreadcrumbBuilder implements BreadcrumbBuilderInterface {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    return preg_match('/view\.your_view_name\./', $route_match->getRouteName());
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    $breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
    $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Home'), ''));
    $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($this->t('something'), ''));
    $breadcrumb->addCacheTags(['config:views.view.youviewname']);
    $breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(['url.path']);
    $params = $route_match->getParameters();
    if ($params->has('arg_0') && !empty($params->get('arg_0'))) {
      $title = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $params->get('arg_0')));
      $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($title, ''));
    }
    return $breadcrumb;
  }
}
```

The above is not an exact example fit to your requirement but show you how to get in and change the breadcrumbs ect.

or look at examples for "hook_system_breadcrumb_alter",  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_system_breadcrumb_alter/8.2.x